# Permissions when creating a simple Python package for pip

Tags: ubuntu, python, pip

I'm trying to package a simple app I wrote, so that it can be installed on a system using `python setup.py install` and (later) using `pip install awesomeapp`.

The app consists of two files in the same directory:

```
awesomeapp
awesomemod.py
```

where `awesomeapp` is the starter script (also in python) which does `import awesomemod`. Everything works and is generally awesome. Next I created a `setup.py` file which looks something like this:

```py
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='awesomeapp',
  version='1.4',
  scripts=['awesomeapp'],
  py_modules=['awesomemod'],
  install_requires=['otherapp>1.0'],
  description='amazing app which does awesome things',
  # ...
  platforms='UNIX',
  long_description='bar',
  )
```

Now, the installation with `sudo python setup.py install` (and also with pip) executes without errors. On OSX everything works as expected. However on Ubuntu (tested with precise and trusty), I get the error:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/awesomeapp", line 12, in <module>
    import awesomemod
ImportError: No module named awesomemod
```

when I run the `awesomeapp` script. However if I run the script using `sudo` the module is found. The module is installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` with `-rw-r-----` permissions which cannot be read by my non-root user. What do I need to change so that normal users do not need root to run my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I found the culprit in my `.bash_profile` file. It included the entry

```
umask 027
```

After commenting the line out, the permissions are fixed!